How to have HTML syntax color and indent in terminal?
I would like to have an experience on working HTML output on terminal as close to what an HTML viewer would provide: indent, syntax color. My closest result is:
curl -L https://example.com | tidy -i 4 -m

But it doesn't have color. Is there a way to add syntax color to the result?
I'm using PowerShell in Windows Terminal in Windows, but I guess it doesn't really matter.

What OS? What terminal? Please [edit] the question are it cannot currently be answered.

@DavidPostill Is it better?
